# Quota remaining is negative

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

I think I must be doing something very stupid, that I just can't see

I just registered an app, in the last ~10 minutes.

I have just been going to the /info route, no authentication or anything else.

The Quota Max says 300, I thought it was supposed to be 10,000 if you have a key?

More bizarrely the Quota remaining is negative, not just in that it has a - sign before, but the absolute value of it increases between requests, e.g. from -3700 to -3701.

I've haven't made anywhere near 300 requests, let alone the 4000 it seem to be reporting.

It doesn't matter whether I include the key or not, the Quota values are the same. It is also the same problem on the questions route, so it is not just Info.

I am only doing Unit tests, so there is no way I have accidentally sent 1000s of requests at once.

I hesitate to tag this as bug, because likely I've done something wrong.

Comment: No, this is a bug I'm pretty sure.  An odd one I can't reproduce, but I've got some other reports of it so I'm sure it's happening.  I'll be deploying some extra instrumentation to figure it out soon-ish.

Comment: If there's anything I give you (url, response etc) to help, just say.

Comment: A potential fix has been deployed, let me know if it happens again.  I'm leaving some logging stuff around for a few more days to see if it comes back.

Comment: @KevinMontrose, this bug is back again, the docs API console returns ~-300, and without a key returns ~-10400, one of my keys returns ~-700

Comment: there's been another round of fixes around this, think I figured it out.  (Combo of code and networking oddities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitoring code has been watching quotas for "impossible" values for a few weeks now and not seen anything, looks like the last round of fixes knocked it out.